# Create two buttons with same function - open drawer div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, navigation-drawer

I was hoping someone could help me to figure this out -- My design currently has a drawer that uses a JQuery animate function to open and close when a user clicks on the tab. I would like to create an additional button that performs the same function (just an alternate way of opening and closing the same exact drawer).

My current button is a#handler_bottom with the following JQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        var h_bt = 0; //variable to keep track of the div#bottom condition.

        $('a#handler_bottom').on('click', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            if (h_bt == 0) {

                $(this).parent().animate({
                    top: '380px'
                }, 300);
                $(this).css({
                    'background-color': '#abadb4'
                });

                h_bt = 1;
            } else {

                $(this).parent().animate({
                    top: '560px'
                }, 300);
                $(this).css({
                    'background-color': '#abadb4'
                });

                h_bt = 0;
            }
        });
```

I've included a fiddle to better show what I'd like to achieve [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs7bv59n/33/). I would like to use the blue circle (#btntwo) to work as an additional button to open the bottom drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your click handler so that you can reuse it.

```
$('a#handler_bottom').on('click', openDrawer)
$('#btntwo').on('click', openDrawer)

function openDrawer(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var drawer = $('#todo');

  if (h_bt == 0) {

    drawer.animate({
      top: '380px'
    }, 300);
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': '#abadb4'
    });

    h_bt = 1;
  } else {

    drawer.animate({
      top: '560px'
    }, 300);
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': '#abadb4'
    });

      h_bt = 0;
  }
}
```

Notice that I also changed reference of `$(this).parent()` to the drawer itself. The context will change depending on what triggers the click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#btntwo").on('click', function(event){ $("a#handler_bottom").click()});
```